# PowerShell to Print Sites MasterPage from a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing, sharepoint, master-pages

**This is for SharePoint Online**

I have a CSV that lists the name of sites and their URL. It contains 2 columns:

SiteName and SiteURL

I'm am attempting to create a powershell script that will read through the CSV file, read the SiteURL. Then Have it return the name of the site and the MasterPage it's using. The results can either be returned on screen or exported to another CSV.

Below is the code I'm trying but I'm having trouble adding the correct CMDLETS. I'm fairly new to PowerShell any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
connect-SPOService -Url $adminUrl -Credential $pscreds

$fileToRead= Import-CSV -Path C:\...\sitemasterpages.csv

foreach($site in $fileToRead)
{
    $web = Get-Pnpweb($site.SiteUrl); 
    $masterPage = $web.GetFile($web.MasterUrl);
    $masterPage.Name 
    $web.Title 
}
```

I get this error message when I run the script 
[image: Error When I run the script]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a collection of `$siteurls` you can try something similar to below:

```
foreach($url in $siteurls)
{
    $web = Get-SPWeb($url);
    $masterPage = $web.GetFile($web.MasterUrl);
    $masterPage.Name //name of the masterpage
    $web.Title //name of the website
}
```

Let me know if this works.

**EDIT**

**Updated Answer**: This includes reading the CSV files and processing line by line. Some assumptions are as follows:

1. You have two columns called `SiteName` and `SiteUrl`
2. Your CSV file is actually comma delimited. If not you need to use the `-delimeter` switch when reading the CSV file.

The updated code would now be:

```
$fileToRead= Import-CSV -Path <absolute path of your CSV file here>

foreach($site in $fileToRead)
{
    $web = Get-SPWeb($site.SiteUrl); //this reads the SiteUrl value in the current line
    $masterPage = $web.GetFile($web.MasterUrl);
    $masterPage.Name //name of the masterpage
    $web.Title //name of the website
}
```

**EDIT**

**Updated Answer to use SharePoint PNP**

connect-SPOService -Url $adminUrl -Credential $pscreds

```
$fileToRead= Import-CSV -Path C:\...\sitemasterpages.csv

foreach($site in $fileToRead)
{
    $web = Get-Pnpweb($site.SiteUrl); 
    $masterPage = $web.Get-Pnpfile($web.MasterUrl);
    $masterPage.Name 
    $web.Title 
}
```

Note that I used Get-Pnpfile based from the documentation of SharePoint PnP [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/powershell/GetPnPFile.md).

Comment: Yes I have a CSV with 2 columns. SiteName and SiteURL. I'm trying to get Powershell to look inside the CSV > Read the "SiteURL" column > Then either print to the screen or export to another CSV the URL and the master page it’s using.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include reading the CSV file. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm still fairly new to powershell. I keep getting this error message about the Getfile method invocation failed.

"Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web] does not contain a 
method named 'GetFile'."

Comment: Can you update your question with your entire code and point out exactly where the error is coming from?

Comment: I updated my answer based on your code. Apologies as I didn't notice that you were using PnP at first. I just replaced GetFile with Get-Pnpfile and it should work now. Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: I receive a message stating:

"Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web] does not contain a 
method named 'Pnpfile' "

Comment: make sure to include Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File in your code